# How to fetch one of each record from table with an SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, records

I have table containing information about a series of x number of quizzes.
It includes a field for ID, Name, Subject and Level.

I would like to be able to fetch all the subjects once, so not the duplicates, because some quizzes will have the same subject.

I am then going to populate a drop down menu with this result and allow user to use it to filter their search results - if I can!

What I am stuck on is the SQL query, and I would be so grateful for any suggestions, thanks in advance!

Comment: Need to normalise your database schema and have a separate table for subjects. Rather than using the distinct query on the questions table.

Comment: You need a separate table subjects to make this easier then and the table you're describing will have subject_id as a foreign key. your SQL query is then `select * from subjects`

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers, the DISTINCT method worked, I did try having a separate table for subjects but it made other parts of my program a bit confusing :p

Comment: Do any of you know a quick way to count the results? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Subject is a text field containing something like Math or English.

```
select distinct subject from quizzes
```

Or for db's that lake distinct

```
select subject from quizzes group by subject
```

It is 'proper' however if you [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) subject/level into its own table since that information is probably repeated over and over for each quiz.

Answer (score 1):

`distinct` is what you want:

```
select distinct subject from thetable;
```

Add an `order by` if you need/want to.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for subjects without duplicate values

```
SELECT DISTINCT Subject FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT subject FROM tbl GROUP BY subject;
```

Does the same as `DISTINCT` in this case.

Comment: Do you know if there is a quick way to count the results? Thanks :)

Comment: @Lissy: `SELECT subject, count(*) AS ct FROM tbl GROUP BY subject;`

Answer (score 1):

This will bring back everything from the `subject` column, but without the duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Subject FROM myTableName
```

You may find that you may be better off having a separate `Subject` table instead of having everything in one big table.